# RawInput loads 100% of my first CPU core and doesn't update properly

Tags: c++, input, raw-input

When I register RawInput, I check all the returns of the functions, everything is fine.However, when I update it it clogs up the performance on my 1st CPU core and it doesn't work properly(when I check if the 'M' button is pressed and have it create a message box when it is, it doesn't just trigger when I press 'M', but it triggers whenever I press anything or move the mouse.Also the message box doesn't come out, there's only a beep.)
Here's the code I use to initialize it:

```
    const ushort usageTable[] = 
    {
        InputDeviceUsage::UsageMouse,
        InputDeviceUsage::UsageKeyboard,
        InputDeviceUsage::UsageGamepad,
    };

    const ulong flagsTable[] = 
    {
        mouseFlags,
        keyboardFlags,
        hidFlags
    };

    const List<SystemDevices>& systemDevices = EnumerateSystemDevices();

    List<String> deviceNames;
    List<InputDeviceInfo> deviceInfo;

    for(uint i = 0; i < systemDevices.Size(); i++)
    {
        deviceNames.Add(GetDeviceName(systemDevices[i].hDevice));
        deviceInfo.Add(GetDeviceInfo(systemDevices[i].hDevice));

        InputDevice device = 
        {
            InputDeviceUsagePage::UsagePageHID,
            usageTable[deviceInfo[i].dwType],
            flagsTable[deviceInfo[i].dwType],
            window
        };

        RegisteredDevices.Add(device);
        Devices[systemDevices[i].hDevice] = CreateDevice(deviceInfo[i].dwType);
```

Where List is the equivalent of **std::vector<>** and these are the typedefs and defines involved:

```
enum InputDeviceUsagePage
{
    UsagePageHID = 0x01
};

enum InputDeviceUsage 
{
    UsageMouse = 0x02,
    UsageKeyboard = 0x06,
    UsageGamepad = 0x04
};

enum InputDeviceType
{
    TypeMouse = RIM_TYPEMOUSE,
    TypeKeyboard = RIM_TYPEKEYBOARD,
    TypeHID = RIM_TYPEHID
};

enum InputDeviceChangeBehavior
{
    Arrival = GIDC_ARRIVAL,
    Removal = GIDC_REMOVAL
};

enum InputDeviceDataRequest
{
    PreparseData =  RIDI_PREPARSEDDATA,
    Name =  RIDI_DEVICENAME,
    Info = RIDI_DEVICEINFO 
};
```

And this is the **Update** function:

```
    try
    {
        InputData data;
        RawDevice::UpdateUnbuffered(reinterpret_cast<HRAWINPUT>(lparam), &data);

        DevicePtr it = Devices[data.header.hDevice];

        if(it == nullptr)
        {   
            DevicePtr newDevice = CreateDevice(data.header.dwType);

            Devices.Add(data.header.hDevice, newDevice);

            if(data.header.hDevice != null) 
            {
                it = newDevice;
            }
        }

        DevicePtr device = it;

        device->Read(data);

        switch(data.header.dwType) 
        {
            case InputDeviceType::TypeMouse:
                {
                    const RawMouse& mouse = static_cast<RawMouse&>(*device);

                    //TODO: add event handling here
                    break;
                }

            case InputDeviceType::TypeKeyboard:
                {
                    const RawKeyboard& keyboard = static_cast<RawKeyboard&>(*device);

                    //TODO: add event handling here
                    break;
                }

            case InputDeviceType::TypeHID:
                {
                    const RawHID& hid = static_cast<RawHID&>(*device);

                    //TODO: add event handling here
                    break;
                }

            default:
                {

                }
        }   
        return(exit_success);
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        return(DefWindowProc(window, message, wparam, lparam));
    }
```

So for instance in the places that have *//TODO: add event handling here* I put:

```
            case InputDeviceType::TypeKeyboard:
                {
                    const RawKeyboard& keyboard = static_cast<RawKeyboard&>(*device);

                    if(keyboard.KeyDown('M'))
                    {
                        MessageBox(window, L"Pressed key is 'M'", L"Input event", MB_OK);
                    }
                    break;
                }
```

I get a beep every time I press any key or any button on the mouse, not just M and also the message box doesn't show, the window just beeps.And the CPU core gets loaded to the maximum.This is the **KeyDown()** function:

```
const bool RawKeyboard::KeyDown(ushort key) const
{
    if(_data.VKey == key && !(_data.Flags & KeyActions::KeyDown))
    {
        return(true);
    }
    {
        return(false);
    }
}
```

**DevicePtr** is basically a **RawDevice*** which contains a name and **DeviceInfo** and from **RawDevice** inherits **RawMouse**, **RawKeyboard** and **RawHID**, which in them have **RAWMOUSE**, **RAWKEYBOARD**, **RAWHID** members named **_data**.

EDIT: Just to add the place where Update is called:

```
            case WM_INPUT:
                {
                    return(_input.Update(_mainWindow.GetHandle(), message, wparam, lparam));
                }
                break;
```

EDIT2: Forgot to add the ReadUnbuffered method:

```
    void RawDevice::UpdateUnbuffered(const HRAWINPUT rawInput, RAWINPUT* data)
    {
        wint64 size(sizeof(RAWINPUT));

        boolresult = GetRawInputData(rawInput, RID_INPUT, data, &size, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER));

        if(result == false)
        {
            throw RawInputException(GetLastError(), L"GetRawInputData()");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Everything points at you not actually reading the input when you get WM_INPUT.  No idea what this code is trying to do but clearly there's no obvious call to GetRawInputData().

Comment: oh sorry, forgot to add the ReadUnbuffered function, now I added it as an edit to the question

Comment: Impossible to dig through this morass of code.  You'll need to do this the other way around, get very basic code working first.  Add the jingle bells from there.  Start with the boiler plate SDK code http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645546%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

your message loop needs to process all messages in the queue before updating you application.

sounds like you are poping the first message switching to your app. filling the msg queue, getting one message, filling the queue some more... you get the point